# Towel radiator T-piece points the wrong way?

Tags: plumbing

I'm attempting to install an element in a towel radiator to convert it to dual fuel. However, when I screw in the T-piece, the T points to the front of the radiator, which would take some creative plumbing to route back to the inlet.

How do I make it point to the rear or side instead? Do I just need to add an extra washer so it won't tighten so far?

Comment: Please edit to add pictures of the problem.

Comment: Duel fuel towel radiator ???

Comment: Use some teflon tape. If one wrap doesn't do it - try two.